# If statement contains part of the text

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am retrieving the current url, this can result in:

`http://www.postyourquestion.com`
and
`http://www.testedyourquestion.com`

Then I want to do a if statement like:

```
if (site.contains("post")
{}
elseif (site.contains("tested")
{}
```

I want to do the if statement on one word (e.g. post or tested).

Right now it steps out of the statement when I do what i wrote here.

Any suggestions?

And yes I looked on google and this forum and havent been able to find anything that solves this issue.

Comment: can you please post the value of site.

Comment: or at least post a piece of code that compiles... and what sort of error you're getting instead of 'steps out'

Comment: Do you want to check the URL for those strings or the text on the site? Strings have the built in function "Contains" which will return true if a string contains another string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Im not getting an error. Its just not stepping into the if statement that I described above because it compares the complete url and I only want to match one word. If that word is in that url.

I pick the url and put it in a string with the name 'xxx'. The Url looks like:
https://home.postyourquestions/some/something.aspx?ID=34345234

Comment: @xxx2017 if you want any help provide minimal verifiable example please... otherwise we just can't help you. But likely by doing so you will find out what's wrong on your own in this case....

Comment: So your string isnt 'site'? You should check if the string 'xxx' contains the strings you are looking for: `if(xxx.Contains("post")`

Comment: the xxx string contains my current url. But when I try to filter it based on 1 work in the if statement it is not considered to be "true".

Comment: you could take the URL with that `driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(s)`